# onclick HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DisciplinasMatriculadas</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <BODY style="font-family: sans-serif">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Matricula de aluno em disciplina</legend>
            <form action="/myform" method="GET">
            ID Aluno: <input type="text" name="aluno" id="aluno">
            <br/>
            ID Disciplina: <input type="text" name="disc" id="disc">
            <br/>
            </form>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDisciplina();alert('Done.');">
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi,
I'm trying to make this onclick function work (newbie here), but I can't figure out what is the problem. Could you guys help me, please?

PS: The index.js works fine if I run it by CMD.

Thanks!

PS2: I've edited like you guys said, but still didn't work. Here's the js:

```
addDisciplina = function() {

var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
app.get('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    var aluno = req.query.aluno;
    var disc = req.query.disc; 
}); 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "161616",
 database: "matricula"
});

var post  = {idDisciplinasMatriculada: aluno*3+disc*2, idDisciplina: disc, idAluno: aluno};

connection.query('INSERT INTO DisciplinasMatriculadas SET ?', post, function(err, result) {});

}
```

Comment: There must be some error in your javascript code.

Comment: what's the code of addDisciplina();

Comment: I've edited the original post with the code :)

Comment: The index.js is NodeJs code, it will not run by frontend side,  what you need to do is to create a route(RESTFUL API), and make a ajax call or http request.

Answer (score 1):

you're closing `</select>` while there are no `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>DisciplinasMatriculadas</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="index.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="font-family: sans-serif">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Matricula de aluno em disciplina</legend>
        <form action="/myform" method="GET"><select>
        ID Aluno: <input type="text" name="aluno" id="aluno"></select>
        <br/>
        <select>
    ID Disciplina: <input type="text" name="disc" id="disc"></select>
    <br/>
    </form>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDisciplina();alert('Done.');">
</fieldset>
```

Correct the Html and try again :)

Comment: I've removed the selects, they were useless, but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in `HTML` file. First of all, you don't need `</select>` at all if you don't have `<select>` tag opened. The `<select>` should be a parent of a child element `<option>`, for example:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can use multiple `onclick` events, just separate them with a semicolon (`;`). Use `<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>` instead of `language="javascript"`, you don't need it and don't forget using a lowercase symbols, it's the best practise. This is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m46jjqn8/1/) for you.

Comment: Done, but still nothing :(